# maven-dependency-plugin copies jars in a wrong way

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-dependency-plugin

In my local repository (`.m2/repository`) I have several jars which I want them to be copied (and referenced) in my project. I have the following `pom.xml` for the `com.google.protobuf` artifact:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>groupName</groupId>
      <artifactId>groupName.master</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>groupName</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
   <name>com.google.protobuf</name>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
   <build>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-installed</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                  <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                  </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

basically I want this plugin to copy the necessary jar file to the folder called build, which is under the module folder itself. It kinda does copy a jar. However when I click and open the jar, I see no files but only manifests. So the references obviously give error. I checked my local repository and the jar is there, and it is properly formed. So the source is not the problem. Something is wrong with the copying process.

Here are the jars of the same artifact. One is taken from the local repository (above) and the other is the so called copied one to the `build` folder. As you can see, the copied one lacks the class files which are found under `com` folder.

[image]

Why does the plugin copy this improperly? Anyone had a similar experience?

**UPDATE:** One thing I noticed is that these two jars have different MANIFEST files inside. Could this be a case that one of the jars is somehow taken from somewhere where it is not supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out. The problem was I defined the artifact in a wrong way. It should have been:

```
                  <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                    <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
                    <destFileName>protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar</destFileName>
                  </artifactItem>
```

Notice the `<name`> tag, which was not correct in my `pom.xml`, therefore the system could not grab the necessary artifact. Also the `destFileName` tag.

Also, above, this was wrong:

```
<groupId>groupName</groupId>
<artifactId>com.google.protobuf</artifactId>
<name>com.google.protobuf</name>
```

If you want to use the one you download from the central repository, you cannot change the `groupId` or `artifactId`. They should stay as they are given in the website of the package.

After fixing these, now I am able to see the class files.

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin pox.xml

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-appCtx</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--copy location-->
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <!--file location-->
                                    <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>test1.jar</include>
                                        <include>test2.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```